# Mongodb connections time out from openwhisk action

Tags: openwhisk

I am running openwhisk via jar on my development box.  I can connect to mongo from node and from the command line.  However, it times out when I try to connect from an openwhisk action.

`curl -u $tok "http://172.17.0.1:3233/api/v1/namespaces/_/actions/openwhiskmongo?blocking=true&result=true" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"jonboy"}' {"error":{"message":"Operation` users.findOne()`buffering timed out after 10000ms","name":"MongooseError","stack":"MongooseError: Operation`users.findOne() `buffering timed out after 10000ms\n    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/nodejsAction/hTFYlZze/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:153:23)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)"}}`

Mongo connects fine from the command line.

```
mongo mongodb://172.17.0.1
MongoDB shell version v4.4.17
connecting to: mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("9777739e-0a81-4ef4-852a-a19a515ac376") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.17
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting: 
        2022-11-21T21:32:14.551-05:00: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
        2022-11-21T21:32:16.601-05:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
---
>
```

172.17.0.1 should be accessible via docker.

```
ifconfig
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:efff:fecc:f630  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:ef:cc:f6:30  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 153  bytes 11410 (11.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 278  bytes 7650054 (7.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here's my action code.

openmongowhisk.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

async function main(args) {
    require('./config/database');
    require('./models/user');
    const User = mongoose.model('User');

    const name = args && args.username;
    var result = 'not initialized';

    var user = await User.findOne({username: name}).exec();

    if (user) {
      result = 'found';
    } else {
      result = 'not found';
    }

    return { user: user, result: result };
}

exports.main = main;
```

database.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const devConnection = "mongodb://172.17.0.1";

mongoose.connect(devConnection, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Database connected');
});
```

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    username: String,
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Edit:add docker network info

````
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "441a18a8d66ef7e29aaae1f2d5fee8b5e2f2edf39200b54a91f0df8b17407a46",
        "Created": "2022-11-19T09:03:56.78026462-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "13d0e2d487f03d2c806a917199857eefd77d9fb216eb9c68647ec5d7e93810e0": {
                "Name": "wsk0_243_prewarm_nodejs14",
                "EndpointID": "938de84937bfe214486713b4490645145a76f85cbff06f7ac49904beba9d8699",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]```

Any ideas?
````

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the proxy settings on my computer, and now it is working.  Can't believe I didn't think of trying that earlier.